# SQL Query outage occurrence time and duration

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and would appreciate if anyone can provide some assistance. I am trying to run a SQL Query which can provide the outage occurrence time and duration based on the samplevalue. Samplevalue =1 is up & Samplevalue = 0 is Down.

link to the 
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZojsA.png)

From above table we have to calculate how much time a particular device is with samplevalue = 0 (down)

Would like to get an output example below

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRn3A.png)

Comment: Most people here want table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Sorry was not being very specific. Its MS SQL 2012.

Answer (score 1):

This code is not checked for syntax errors, but this is the logic for you to imply, Datediff is a sql server function or you can use similar for datediff in other engines.

```
SELECT target,samplevalue,min(sampletime) as StartTime,max(sampletime) as EndTime,datediff(minute,max(sampletime),min(sampletime)) as Outrage
FROM table 
WHERE samplevalue=0
GROUP BY target,samplevalue
```

Comment: Thanks mate i will give it a try tonight.